# React image component not showing PNG image on iOS safari (shows alt text but blank image)

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, tailwind-css

For some reason the following image URL when put as src of the image component displays perfectly on desktop but when opened on iOS safari is blank (I'm using Tailwind CSS by the way):

URL: https://www.media.auledge.com/avatar/ed93a87c-c2da-40d8-9805-0853cf29930c.png

Code:

[image]

Desktop:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Comment: which version of safari are you using. Safari < 15 does not support aspect ratio

Comment: Hmm it looks like my device software version is 15.3.1 but I think you might be right here; let me try without aspect ratio.

Comment: did removing aspect ratio work?